# How to create a doubly linked list of multiple data types

Tags: java, generics, doubly-linked-list

I am currently writing a program that creates Students and stores them in a doubly linked list based on their natural order (Last name, First name, GPA, then student ID). I am just starting off with generics and how they work so I am a little lost. I believe most of my code is working; the only part I need help with is adding students (who have multiple data types) into my list in my main method in my doubly linked list class. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is my student, doubly linked list, and node class along with a fragment of the input file I am reading from with the data of each student:

Student class:

```
public class Student{
long studentID;
String firstName;
String lastName;
float GPA;

public Student(String lastName, String firstName, float GPA, long studentID){
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.GPA = GPA;
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

public int compareTo(Student s){
    int result = this.lastName.compareTo(s.lastName);
    if(result == 0){
        result = this.firstName.compareTo(s.firstName);
        if(result == 0){
            result = Float.compare(this.GPA, s.GPA);
            if(result == 0){
                result = Long.compare(this.studentID, s.studentID);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName +
     " GPA: " + this.GPA + " ID: " + this.studentID;
}

}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node<T>{
Node<T> previous;
Node<T> next;
Student data;

public Node(Student data){
    this(data, null, null);
}

public Node(Student data, Node<T> previous, Node<T> next){
    this.data = data;
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
}
}
```

Doubly Linked List class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import csci1140.*;

public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<Node>{
private Node root;
private Node tail;
private Node previous;

 private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Node>{
    Node current = root;
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return (current != null);
    }


    public Node next(){
        Node answer;

        answer = current;
        current = current.next;

        return answer;
    }

} 

 public Iterator<Node> iterator(){
    ListIterator listIterator = new ListIterator();
    return listIterator;
}  

public void add(T data){
    Node<Student> newNode = new Node<Student>(data);

    if(root == null){
        root = newNode;
        tail = root;
        return;
    }

    Node current = root;
    for( ; current!= null; current = current.next){
        if(newNode.data.compareTo(current.data)<= 0){
            break;
        }

    }

    if(previous == null){
        previous.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = current;
        if(current == null){
            tail = newNode;
        }
    } else {
        newNode.next = root;
        root = newNode;
    }
}

public static final void main(String[] args){

   FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    try{ 
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("student_input.txt"); 
        System.setIn(fileIn);            
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){ 
        fnfe.printStackTrace(System.err); 
    } 

    //Do work here to create list of students

    }
    try{                        
        fileIn.close();         
    } catch(Exception e){}            
}
}
```

Student_input.txt:

```
1000
Lisa
Licata
2.28
1001
Shelley
Santoro
1.56
1002
Ok
Ota
3.33
1003
Cindi
Caggiano
1.65
```

Comment: do you mean "Student data;" -> "T data;"  where T extends Student? Otherwise question is what should T represent if not the data?

Comment: `new DoublyLinkedList<Student>()`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, my mistake

Comment: I just want a list of one type of students that is sorted based off of their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Still not completely sure, maybe some variation of this.

Especially this inserts before the first Node that is bigger,  and I am still not sure what the generics are for in this case and T needs to be something that extends Student(well it needs the compareTo method):

```
public void add(T data) {
    for(Node<T> current = root; current != null; current = current.next) {
        if (data.compareTo(current.data) <= 0) {
            current = new Node<>(data,current.previous,current);
            if(null == current.previous){
                root = current;
            }else {
                current.previous.next = current; 
            }
            if(null == current.next){
               tail = current; 
            } else {
               current.next.previous = current; 
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    tail = new Node<>(data,tail,null);
    if(null == tail.previous) root=tail;
}
```

So your list should maybe look like this(to ensure T has the compareTo method):

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Student> implements Iterable<Node<T>> {
...
}
```

All together(To have Node as a seperate file like you do is better - but for brevity I put it into the list):

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Student> implements Iterable<Node<T>> {

    public static class Node<S> {

        Node<S> previous;
        Node<S> next;
        S data;

        public Node(S data) {
            this(data, null, null);
        }

        public Node(S data, Node<S> previous, Node<S> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
    private Node<T> root = null;
    private Node<T> tail = null;

    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Node<T>> {

        Node<T> current = root;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);
        }

        @Override
        public Node<T> next() {
            Node<T> answer;

            answer = current;
            current = current.next;

            return answer;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node<T>> iterator() {
        ListIterator listIterator = new ListIterator();
        return listIterator;
    }

    public  void add(T data) {
        for(Node<T> current = root; current != null; current = current.next) {
            if (data.compareTo(current.data) <= 0) {
                current = new Node<>(data,current.previous,current);
                if(null == current.previous){
                    root = current;
                }else {
                    current.previous.next = current; 
                }
                if(null == current.next){
                   tail = current; 
                } else {
                   current.next.previous = current; 
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        tail = new Node<>(data,tail,null);
        if(null == tail.previous) root=tail;
    }
}
```